# Declarar una variable con el contenido de un archivo

Tags: batch

En mi script de batch estoy haciendo que el usuario introduzca una localización donde copiar archivos usando `copy con location.tmp`, quiero guardar en una variable el contenido de `location.tmp`, he probado con `set /a instdir=location.tmp` y `set instdir=location.tmp` pero no lo consigo

EDIT: Ya encontré la solución por mi mismo pero gracias por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Prueba ingresando esto:

```
set /p instdir=Carpeta:     
echo %instdir% > location.tmp
```

Comment: Josem : La respuesta se ha ido a la cola de revisión de preguntas de baja calidad por su extensión y contenido. Si bien hay ocasiones en las que podría ser válido que una respuesta incluya sólo código generalmente son mejor recibidas las que incluyen una breve explicación y se tienen cuidado de darles formato apropiado.